# Parameter from controller to form has always null value

Tags: php, symfony

I'd like to pass a parameter from the controller to the form but the parameter has alwyas null value.

This is the Controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(BaseType::class, $entity, array('nom' => 'Informatique'));
```

and this is the FormType

```
 ->add('departement', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'=> 'AppBundle\Entity\Departement',
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'query_builder' => function(DepartementRepository $er ) use($options)  {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                    ->where('d.nom like :nom')
                    ->setParameter('nom', '%' .$options['nom']. '%')
                    ;
            }
        ))

 public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Formation',
        'nom' => null,
    ));
}
```

output of var_dump($options['nom']); is null

Comment: You need to show your code for "DocumentType" class and how do you plan to create the $document object hous?

Comment: @ Alvin Bunk : I have edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of `createForm` is the array `$options` that can contain.. anything you want.

So in your controller:

```
public function yourAction()
{
    $form = $this->createForm(
        DocumentType::class,
        $document,
        ['yourCustomOption' => 'value']
    );
```

And you can access or set a default value in your `FormType`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $yourCustomOption = $options['yourCustomOption']; //will be 'value'
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'yourCustomOption' => 'Default value',
    ));
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but parameter has always null value. I have edited my question

Comment: I never faced a case where this did not work. Are you sure you are not overriding the value somewhere else? Paste your full FormType if possible.

Comment: this is the formType
(https://gist.github.com/houssem04/b1b67009dd5506cf4623155e592fd54b)

Comment: It looks fine to me. I'm using options in my form this way, and I never had an issue. Are you sure that you are checking the form you created with the option and not another one ?

Comment: What do you mean by "with the option and not another one' ?

Comment: Thank you very much , It was a mistake from me. I have passed the parameter in a wrong form in the controller. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Right in your code, you've set 'nom' to **null**, so you probably (I'm guessing) need to change it:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
  $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Formation',
        'nom' => 'some nom value',
  ));
}
```

I don't know why you set it to null and then you were expecting it not to be null??? Did you just overlook this?